# Terms & conditions with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im using Codeigniter to create a login system.
Im new to CI. 
How can I block the direct access to signup. I want to make sure anonymous have to accept the terms before go up to signup view.

view controller

```
<?php $attr_form = array('class' => 'form-horizontal'); 
echo form_open('login/accept', $attr_form); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <?php echo form_checkbox('terms', 'accept', FALSE); ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <?php 
        $data_submit = array('class'=> 'btn btn-info', 'name' => 'submit', 'value'=> 'Accept');
        echo form_submit($data_submit);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
function accept ()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('terms', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        if ($this->input->post('terms'))
        {
            redirect('login/signup');
        }

        else
        {
            $this->terms();
        }
    }
}
```

should I use session library to do the job? or any other simpler methods?

thanks

Comment: you can use sessions or cookies will be more secure

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variable . But you can write the code in user defined controller extending
CI_Controller. And then use this user defined controller to declare other controllers. I would 
save you from writing signup code individually for every controller.